# Count instances using selector

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
var loppNum = parseInt(jQuery('#seire_ulatus_tabel input[name*="sisestusSeireVahemikLopp_"]')
   .filter(function () {
       return this.value != "";
   })
   .length);
```

Is there a way i can use jQuery selector to select all rows that have one or the other field or both fields filled? I have 2 fields on a row. Each row must be counted once.

Im using grails. I have a template where are 2 inputfields. Using this template i can render the rows where needed. I need to be able to count how many rows have atleast 1 field filled.

Comment: One or the other of what fields? Please can you show your HTML, that way the question is useful to future visitors also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)/[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
var elems = jQuery('#seire_ulatus_tabel')   
    .find('input[name*="sisestusSeireVahemikAlgus_"], input[name*="sisestusSeireVahemikLopp_"]').filter(function() {
        return this.value != "";
    });

var parentTrs = elems.closest('tr');
```

Comment: jQuery('#seire_ulatus_tabel input[name*="sisestusSeireVahemikAlgus_"]',
            '#seire_ulatus_tabel input[name*="sisestusSeireVahemikLopp_"]') something like this wont work ??

Comment: @MarkoTaht, that should work. However you can also try `jQuery('#seire_ulatus_tabel').find('input[name*="sisestusSeireVahemikAlgus_"], input[name*="sisestusSeireVahemikLopp_"]')`